# Exclude files on ant deployment

Tags: deployment, ant, jenkins

What if I want all the classes EXCEPT a few?

For example, if I have a scheduled batch that definitely won't deploy, how would I say "not that" but not have to manually name all the other ones?

Caveats...this is via Jenkins GitHub plugin,, not mavens or eclipse.

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything you can do via the package.xml itself, but perhaps you can script something to automate a package.xml creation with metadata references and exclude the ones you know you can't deploy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately ant migration tool does not look at `includes` / `excludes` attributes or elements.

If it's a regular thing, how about using `ant` to snip it out of your `package.xml` on the fly?

```
<target name="almostDeploy">
    <!-- put yo stuff away -->
    <replace file="src/package.xml"
    token="&lt;members&gt;YOUR_CLASS_HERE&lt;/members&gt;"
    value="&lt;!--members&gt;YOUR_CLASS_HERE&lt;/members--&gt;" />

    <!-- normal salesforce deploy -->
    <sf:deploy
    username="${sf.username}"
    password="${sf.password}"
    serverurl="https://login.salesforce.com"
    deployRoot="src"/>

    <!-- put stuff back yo -->
    <replace file="src/package.xml"
    token="&lt;!--members&gt;YOUR_CLASS_HERE&lt;/members--&gt;"
    value="&lt;members&gt;YOUR_CLASS_HERE&lt;/members&gt;" />
</target>
```

Comment: Nice tweak! To get use of the Ant exclude/include filters back one could copy files to be deployed to a temp folder using the filters and leverage wildcards in the package.xml as well. Bit more work then your nice use of replace above, but maybe a thought if the requirement grows more complex.

Comment: Very clever, 320.  You're the winner.